# valgrind not able find memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have encountered a weird issue. A process(written in c) is leaking memory but I am not able to locate why it is happening. Memory usage is increasing continuously when process handles traffic and at some point OS(linux) is killing it with error 'out of memory'.

I tried to debug this using valgrind with the following flags:

```
--show-reachable=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --track-fds=yes --num-callers=20 --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-out.txt
```

Output file is as follows:

```
==5564== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5564==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5564==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5564==      possibly lost: 646,916 bytes in 1,156 blocks
==5564==    still reachable: 4,742,112 bytes in 2,191 blocks
==5564==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Definitely lost is shown as 0 and there is no indication on where it is leaking. I have gone through still reachable segment, they all seem fine.
I wont be able to post code as it is a huge code with 100k+ lines. Basically what it does it sends some packets over tcp socket as a client. Sever is a simple python script which replies with response. My codes works as expected. This leak is the only trouble.

Any suggestion on debugging this issue?

Comment: Increase in memory usage does not automatically indicate a memory leak.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, but memory usage is continuously increasing with every request/response flow. This is a concern.

Comment: Since the program is 100K+ lines long, it is not that simple as you are describing. Maybe it is adding some data to some data structure with each request, for example? It is really hard to tell how to approach it without seeing the code, as the "generic" tools such as Valgrind are not helpful as you see.

Comment: It's possible that there's no "real" leak, and the program is able to clean up everything properly on exit which is why you don't see anything in the summary. Do you use custom memory pools/allocators? Valgrind wouldn't necessarily catch memory leaks in a custom pool, but the pool is able to free everything on exit.

Comment: We need to see the _relevant_ code. That is, code that does `malloc/free`.Please _edit_ your question and post it in a code block here. Desk checking: For every allocation, where does the block get freed? Another way: write wrapper functions that intercept/log all these calls. If you can compile, you can do (e.g.) `#define malloc(_siz) logging_malloc(_siz)` Otherwise, with `glibc`, you can use "hook" functions (e.g.): `__malloc_hook`. See the man3 pages for `mcheck`, `mtrace`, `mallopt`, `malloc_info`

Comment: Or, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to inject your wrapper functions from a `.so` that you create (e.g.): `void * malloc(size_t size) { static void *(real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;  if (real_malloc == NULL) real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc");  /* do whatever tracing ... */  void *ptr = real_malloc(size);  return ptr; }`

Comment: "Any suggestion on debugging this issue?" How about telling is a) which version of Valgrind b) which version of Linux and which platform c) more details about your memory allocation methods? @Kevin makes a very pertinent suggestion.

Comment: You might consider debugging it by using https://github.com/vmware/chap

Comment: valgrind provides "differential" leak search to see how the allocated memory evolves between 2 leak searches.  With this, you can start your program and have it initialised. You then run a leak search. After your application has processed some more data, you do a leak search asking to show the "increased" memory. This can show the increase of lost/leaked memory but also the allocated memory. Leak search can be triggered from the shell using vgdb . See leak_search in https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands.